# Why does my ajax function return false?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The `saveTask()` function calls `requestJSONAJAX`, but the `requestJSONAJAX` function returns `false`. This happens even though the query on my `tasklog.php` is successful; it even updates my database. I don't know where my error originates. Is it in my `tasklog.php` or in the JavaScript functions, or am I using the `return` wrong?

```
function saveTask(){
    if(requestJSONAJAX('add')){
        goSuccess();
    }else{
        alert('error');
    }
}

function requestJSONAJAX(action){
    var newObj;
    if(action == "add"){
        newObj = {  action: "add", 
                date: $("#date").val(), 
                taskName: $("#taskName").val(),
                taskType: $("#taskType").val(),
                duration: $("#duration").val(),
                startTime: $("#startTime").val(),
                endTime: $("#endTime").val()
            }
    }else if(action == "login"){
        newObj = {  action: "login", 
                    username: $("#username").val(), 
                    password: $("#password").val()
                }
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:"../_tasklogger/classes/tasklog.php", //the page containing php script
        dataType: 'json',
        data: newObj,
        success: function(data){
            status = data;
            if(status == "success"){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
        }
    });
}
```

tasklog.php

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(empty($_POST['action'])){
    return;
}

if(($_POST['action']) != "getData"){
    $date= $_POST['date'];
    $taskName= $_POST['taskName'];
    $taskType= $_POST['taskType'];
    $duration= $_POST['duration'];
    $startTime= $_POST['startTime'];
    $endTime= $_POST['endTime'];
}

switch($_POST['action']){
    case "add":
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (taskDate,taskName,taskType,duration,startTime,endTime,userId) VALUES(:tdate, :tname, :ttype, :dur, :stime, :etime, 1)";
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tdate", $date);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tname", $taskName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ttype", $taskType);
        $stmt->bindParam(":dur", $duration);
        $stmt->bindParam(":stime", $startTime);
        $stmt->bindParam(":etime", $endTime);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo json_encode("success");
        }else{
            echo json_encode("error");
        }
        break;
    case "getData":

        break;
    case "delete":
       /* .... some code .... */
       break;
    case "update": 
       /* some code ... 
             notice there is no "break" here... and execution continues to the next case.... falls-thru */

    default:
         return;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return *anything* from `requestJSONAJAX`. You return a boolean from your `success` handler in your `$.ajax()` call, but that's irrelevant. That doesn't make the function *containing* that `$.ajax()` call—that is, `requestJSONAJAX`—return anything.

It seems like you're trying to return a value from `requestJSONAJAX` based on your AJAX call's success or failure. That's impossible; that's why it's called "AJAX" (*Asynchronous* JavaScript and XML). `requestJSONAJAX` will (essentially) always finish before the AJAX call does. Even when it doesn't finish first, it's not waiting on the AJAX call, and it has no way of telling whether the call succeeded or failed.

To capture whether the call was successful, you'd need to set a flag somewhere (like a global variable). Even better, just handle whatever you want to do within that `success` handler. Don't worry about returning a value.

Comment: I see. Now I understand why my ajax function dont return a value. Thank you for the informative reply it's a big help especially for me who's just beginning to study ajax. Thanks!